# XY points not showing up on map after adding new rows to attribute table

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, geometry

In QGIS, I added two new rows, but the points are not showing up on my map even though I inputted their LAT and LONG's. The rest of the rows LAT/LONGs show up on the map (they were part of the original table I added). I already went into field calculator and specified that LAT was $y and LONG was $x...but that didn't solve the problem. How do I get the points to show up?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the field calculator to update the feature's geometry. From the "Update existing field" dropdown select the "< geometry >" option. Then enter an expression like

```
make_point("LONG","LAT")
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you see in the attribute table are just that, attributes. Geometries are not visible there. You cannot edit geometries there. LAT and LONG are just names of some attributes your data has, they are not the geometric coordinates of your points.

You might have to use CSV import or manually add/edit the geometries. There might be a plugin to manually enter coordinates for new geometries.